# Camel check header value after split

Tags: apache, groovy, split, header, apache-camel

I have a problem in my Camel Route when I try to check the value of a header.
So what is happening is that I go to a processor, do my stuff, then I create 2 different message that I put inside the body.
After that I go back on my route, I split my body so I can route the 2 differents messages, and there I use a .choice().when() on the header CamelFileName to check if it contains some value.
It doesn't find the value and then doesn't go inside the .when()

Here is the source code to make it more clear :

```
// My route
from("myQuartz")
    .routeId("myId")
    .bean(myProcessor.class)
    .split(body())
    .to("log:test?showAll=true&multiline=true")
    .log('[${header.CamelFileName}]')
    .choice()
        .when(header('CamelFileName').contains('myString1'))
            // do my stuff
        .endChoice()
        .when(header('CamelFileName').contains('myString2'))
            // do my other stuff
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .log("It did not go inside the when")
            .to("log:test?showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .endChoice()
    .end()
```

So here I am simply trying to check if the CamelFileName header contains a string (it's not a variable), but it keep going inside the otherwise.
The log just after the split show me that the CamelFileName header is correct and do contains the string I am looking for.

I tried different ways of checking the value inside the when() such as using a simple(), but it doesn't work. 
My file is a groovy file.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :
So to explain what is inside my body I will show you the processor source code.
I create two DefaultMessage, 
I set them a body and a CamelFileName header, 
I put them into a list and then I put that list into my exchange body. 
After that I go back to the route and I split the body so it will separate the two messages and route them.
Here is what's happening in my processor :

```
// Message 1 
DefaultMessage message1 = new DefaultMessage()
message1.setBody(bodyContent)
def fileName1 = "myString1_blablabla.txt"
message1.setHeader("CamelFileName",fileName1)
listMessages.add(message1)

// Message 2
DefaultMessage message2 = new DefaultMessage()
message2.setBody(bodyContent)
def fileName2 = "myString2_blablabla.txt"
message2.setHeader("CamelFileName",fileName2)
listMessages.add(message2)

exchange.in.setBody(listMessages)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a simpler test for your route. It routes data to the proper `when` clause. When you `split()`, the headers get copied for each exchange, so I'm not sure why you would expect (given your route) why the elements of the list would have different header values.

```
public class SampleTest extends CamelTestSupport{
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("myString1"))
                .split(body())
                .choice()
                    .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("myString1"))
                        .to("mock:myString1")
                    .endChoice()
                    .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("myString2"))
                        .to("mock:myString2")
                    .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("mock:otherwise")
                    .endChoice()
                .end();
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //Setup mock body
        java.util.List<String> myList = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("1");
        myList.add("2");

        MockEndpoint mock1 = getMockEndpoint("mock:myString1");
        MockEndpoint mock2 = getMockEndpoint("mock:myString2");
        MockEndpoint mockOtherwise = getMockEndpoint("mock:otherwise");

        mock1.expectedMessageCount(myList.size());
        mock2.expectedMessageCount(0);
        mockOtherwise.expectedMessageCount(0);

        template.sendBody("direct:start", myList);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it's because in my processor I am creating 2 differents messages off Type DefaultMessage. Each of them have a different body and CamelFileName header. Then I put them into a list and I put that list into my exchange body. After that I go back on my route and I split the body so it will separate the two messages and route them. I just updated my first post to show you the processor source code that does this part.

Comment: You're doing something odd, and I'm afraid it needs more explaining than I can give here. Don't use `DefaultMessage`, it's an internal class. You interact with messages on the exchange with `exchange.in.setBody()` and `exchange.in.setHeader()`. In your processor you've made your body a message instance...which is wrong. Try reading through the "Getting Started" guide for a clearer understanding of how to use the exchange and messages.

Comment: I need to create two messages in the same processor and then route them.
If I don't put a list of message in my body and then split them, it will route only one message. How could I do that other way ?

Comment: You could use the same setup as you have now, but you'd have to give the expression `simple("${in.body.header('CamelFileName')}")` instead of `header("CamelFileName")`. It's just weird to use the `DefaultMessage` object.

Comment: It didn't work. I had to use a .groovy() expression in my route to make it work. Can't find another way to do it.